# Why is REPLACE not working in my SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure. Currently queries are being stored in variables. For example:

```
@sample = 'SELECT * FROM WS_CoolApp_ASample'
@sample += 'Where DATASOURCE.FName = @finder AND DATASOURCE.Age = 23'
```

I want to remove that 'DATASOURCE.' from the query if a condition is true. So far I've tried:

```
IF (true)
    REPLACE(@sample, "DATASOURCE.", "")
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Which database engine is this, is it SQL Server? Please be explicit.

Comment: Also, your SQL string needs an additional space character after the table name or it runs into the where clause.

Comment: @DavidG It did have the `tsql` tag.

Comment: Yes, it is SQL Server

Answer (score 3):

You aren't assigning the output of REPLACE() to anything.

```
@sample = REPLACE(@sample, 'DATASOURCE.', '')
```

Comment: Ok, actually you were right. I had an if statement with an else statement below it and I changed it to this in the if statement but forgot to do it in the else statement. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
DECLARE @sample as nvarchar(500)

set @sample = 'SELECT * FROM WS_CoolApp_ASample';
set @sample += 'Where DATASOURCE.FName = @finder AND DATASOURCE.Age = 23';

-- assign the replaced string back to @sample
set @sample = REPLACE(@sample, 'DATASOURCE.', '')

PRINT @sample

-- prints -> SELECT * FROM WS_CoolApp_ASampleWhere FName = @finder AND Age = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sample nvarchar(max)
SET @sample = 'SELECT * FROM WS_CoolApp_ASample'
SET @sample += 'Where DATASOURCE.FName = @finder AND DATASOURCE.Age = 23'

SELECT REPLACE(@sample,'DATASOURCE.','')
```

I hope this works.

Comment: You missed the space between the table and WHERE
Also what about the conditional check?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sample nvarchar(max)
SET @sample = 'SELECT * FROM WS_CoolApp_ASample '
SET @sample += 'Where DATASOURCE.FName = @finder AND DATASOURCE.Age = 23'
if(@bit_var = 1)
  SET @sample = REPLACE(@sample,'DATASOURCE.','')
```